# How to build llvm packaged in Android Sources?

Tags: android, llvm, llvm-3.0

I'm trying to build llvm that is packaged in android sources.

I'm running ubuntu 12.04, with android src version 4.0.4

The llvm is located in android-src/external/llvm/

I did the following to build:

```
./configure
make
```

And the following error message showed up:

```
llvm[3]: Compiling Thumb2InstrInfo.cpp for Debug+Asserts build
ARMJITInfo.cpp:18:10: fatal error: 'ARMAddressingModes.h' file not found
#include "ARMAddressingModes.h"
    ^
```

I can build my local llvm fine with version: 3.2

The version for the android llvm I couldn't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by copying over the missing header file "ARMAddressingModes.h" from my local llvm install.